# Data persistence in an iOS-Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, persistence

I am creating a fairly simple game in Swift and I am unsure of which data persistence method would be best suited for the project. This is my first "real" project so please excuse my ignorance.

I have to be able to store the following data for users: 
- On/Off states for game sound 
- The users' high-score 
- A game currency unit that users may purchase In-App 
- An indicator of whether Ads are enabled or disabled in the game

Also the user has to be able to restore all data from iCloud (I know that's a whole separate issue). Can I accomplish this with just NSUserDefaults/plists or is this more up the alley of Core Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is NSUserDefaults. Yes you can save those small settings.

There is also iOS keychain to store the sensitive data like amount of currency but I don't think it is that important to keep it in the keychain.
If you are interested in the keychain check out this repository.

[Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith)

Finally if you try to save the settings in the iCloud you can use the iCloud key value storage.

[iCloud Preference storage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html)

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults is great for storing very small amounts of data. In your case this may be a good choice.

Comment: i understand NSUserDefaults, but in the case of 'Game currency', is this something that should be stored on a server to avoiding hacking?